# How to process data outputted by $.post in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

i'm using $.post() to send result to the controller and model. it outputs a whole page with all tags.. , .. so on. i want to process those outputted data. how can i do this? for an example below code, i want to get the value of id='myid' within outputted data.

```
$.post(url, function(data) {
   alert(data.getElementById('ContentPane').html());
});
```

help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(data).find('#ContentPane').html()
```

didn't work for me but then i used

```
   $(data).filter('#ContentPane').html()
```

it worked! thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you had more than one element in the page with the id 'ContentPane' and `.find` was selecting the wrong one. `.filter` will select all 'ContentPane' ids.. I wouldn't use `.filter` on this, if you have multiple elements with the same id, chances are you'll return the wrong result some of the time. Its better to use `.find` and actually define a better path to the element.

Comment: i'm having trouble selecting <html> tag and its attributes from this output. `$(response).filter('html')` or even `find()` doesn't work. please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388596/how-to-process-get-and-catch-html-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert returned HTML code to an object. Try with:

```
$(data).find('#ContentPane').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the below:

```
$.post(url, function(data) {
   alert($(data).find("#ContentPane").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this

```
$(data).find("#ContentPane").html()
```

Assuming `ContentPane` is the control you want to find the `data` coming from controller.