# How to process $.get and catch html element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, alert

I'm reading a html document using jQuery. Following is my code. I need to find `lang` attribute which is an attribute of HTML element. But I have trouble selecting it the way I'm doing. when I process HTML tag its either no value, `null` or `undefined`.

Can u please help me figure this out?

```
$.get(page, function(response) {
    alert(response);
    alert($(response).filter('html').attr('lang'));
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$(response)` on the response text, the `html` element gets dropped by most (if not all) browsers. To look at it, I see two options:

1. Process the text as text. Not ideal, but it's not that complicated to parse the attributes on the `<html>` tag. For instance, this should extract the `lang` attribute barring the unusual:

   ```
   var regex = /<\s*html\s[^>]*lang\s*=\s*["']?([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/i;
   var matches = regex.exec(str);
   console.log(matches[1]);
   ```

   [Live example](http://jsbin.com/udezox) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/udezox/edit)

   Usual caveat: HTML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), so you can't reliably parse it with regular expresions. Sometimes a well-tuned regex can extract bits of information from HTML text, and those can be "good enough" when they're rigorously tested with the expected input data, but just beware that they cannot work reliably against all possible HTML source texts.
2. Rather than using `$.get`, create a hidden iframe and assign `page` to it as its `src`. Then use `iframe.contentDocument.documentElement` to access the `html` element, and use `getAttribute` to read its `lang` attribute.

   That might look something like this:

   [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ugesoh) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/ugesoh/edit) | [Source of page being loaded](http://jsbin.com/imeqij/edit)

   ```
   display("Loading the iframe...");
   var $iframe = $("<iframe>");
   $iframe
     .css({
       position: "absolute",
       left: "-10000px"
     })
     .bind("load", function() {
       var doc = $iframe[0].contentDocument,
           html = doc && doc.documentElement,
           lang = html && html.getAttribute("lang");
       if (lang) {
         display("<code>lang = " + lang + "</code>");
         $iframe.remove(); // Or not, as you prefer
       }
     })
     .appendTo(document.body);
   $iframe[0].src = "http://jsbin.com/imeqij";
   ```

   (I've had to be somewhat defensive there because JSBin wraps our page in a frame of its own.)

Comment: your 1st solution. How can i do that? i tried 2nd. it works thanks, but when i use that iframe, my page loads for a longer time showing connecting ...

Comment: The 1st solution is straight-forward string processing. You can't correctly *parse* HTML using regular expressions, but when you want to extract something specific, you can usually make it work. Off the top of my head, the regex `/<\s*html\s[^>]*lang\s*=\s*["']?([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/i` should get pretty close, capturing the value in the first capture group.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i'm a novice for jquery and regex knowledge is very poor. I'm sorry but i don't know how to capture lang value using your regex. Can you please explain a bit further? `var str=response.toString();var regex = /<\s*html\s[^>]*lang\s*=\s*["']?([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/i;var matches = regex.exec(str);` this returns null by the way.

Comment: @guitarlass: You're doing it right. It works for me (somewhat to my surprise; I just dashed that off): http://jsbin.com/udezox I'd walk through with a debugger and make sure that `response` contains what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     var language = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang");
     alert(language);
</script>
```